# Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago…

Tags: php

In this already existing Q a found this :

```
$time_elapsed = timeAgo($time_ago); //The argument $time_ago is in timestamp (Y-m-d H:i:s)format.

//Function definition

function timeAgo($time_ago)
{
    $time_ago = strtotime($time_ago);
    $cur_time   = time();
    $time_elapsed   = $cur_time - $time_ago;
    $seconds    = $time_elapsed ;
    $minutes    = round($time_elapsed / 60 );
    $hours      = round($time_elapsed / 3600);
    $days       = round($time_elapsed / 86400 );
    $weeks      = round($time_elapsed / 604800);
    $months     = round($time_elapsed / 2600640 );
    $years      = round($time_elapsed / 31207680 );
    // Seconds
    if($seconds <= 60){
        return "just now";
    }
    //Minutes
    else if($minutes <=60){
        if($minutes==1){
            return "one minute ago";
        }
        else{
            return "$minutes minutes ago";
        }
    }
    //Hours
    else if($hours <=24){
        if($hours==1){
            return "an hour ago";
        }else{
            return "$hours hrs ago";
        }
    }
    //Days
    else if($days <= 7){
        if($days==1){
            return "yesterday";
        }else{
            return "$days days ago";
        }
    }
    //Weeks
    else if($weeks <= 4.3){
        if($weeks==1){
            return "a week ago";
        }else{
            return "$weeks weeks ago";
        }
    }
    //Months
    else if($months <=12){
        if($months==1){
            return "a month ago";
        }else{
            return "$months months ago";
        }
    }
    //Years
    else{
        if($years==1){
            return "one year ago";
        }else{
            return "$years years ago";
        }
    }
}
```

But how i write to this my number in this formatting ? please help. 
(Sorry for this but this filter dont allow me to post this big code so please ignore this info about nothing only for posting my question ok ignore this thing in brackets I am not engish so sorry. will it work now ?)

Comment: Reverse order of output  - from years to seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give the function any string of time that `strtotime()` accepts: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

i.e. `$time_ago_string = timeAgo('Jan 14th, 2007');`

Comment: I get Epoch time so is there anything to combine theese things together ?

Comment: I think you'd just comment out that first statement (the `strtotime` line)